# What happens in Assassin's Creed 2 when you find all the feathers?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

Getting all the feathers is a grind and tedious for me. Is it worth getting them?

Comment: you can climb a tall building and look around with 'eagle vision' the feathers will glow brightly, this makes it a little easier to spot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's two rewards to collecting the Feathers. With 50, you unlock a special hammer weapon. At 100, you unlock the Auditore Cape, which makes you Notorious.

and just an Achievement or Trophy. Bragging rights really.